# Divergent colour scales with black and white restriction

Tags: r, colors

I have the constraint of being restricted to a greyscale output for a document containing plots and maps made with R.

For line graphs I can use different combinations of shades of grey and linetypes to distinguish multiple lines and in maps continuous or qualitative scales of grey are easy to produce (e.g. with `colorRampPalette`).

However, I need to produce maps with a divergent scale, i.e. from positive to negative values where the further from zero the value, the stronger the colour. However with the greyscale constraint I am wondering how it is possible to distinguish strong positive values from strong negative values in these situations?

Comment: Perhaps use two maps (one for + one for -)? If they are choropleth-y, you can also try to fill in the either the positive or negative side with a pattern to distinguish from the other.

Comment: Thanks, I will try different combinations of angle and density to see what I could produce. I had not thought of this as a solution.